What is the rational for the difference in weight of LCP and FCP in Lighthouse
I was thinking recently about the weights used to produce the final Lighthouse score.
If you hop over to https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/scorecalc/ you can see that these are

0.1 : FCP, SI, TTI
0.15 : CLS
0.25 : LCP
0.3 : TBT

From my observation FCP and LCP are often identical. I struggled to find a solid basis for the heuristic that places much more value on LCP. But, I assume these weights are coming from the HTTP Archive as suggested in their documentation. But on https://httparchive.org/reports/loading-speed I don't see LCP even mentioned. So where is the data on it coming from that then drives the weight or crafts the heuristic.

Web Vitals are user-centric metrics. IMO: the user cares more about the big thing showing up then the first thing showing up. Sometimes, the first paint is not very useful to the user.

I have personally worked on sites with an ocean of time between LCP and FCP. Put serial blocking requests in between domContentLoaded and an image appearing, and you've got problems!

Can imagine that to be the case, for me it's often not. FCP is in parallel the LCP. But we all have our bias given where we work. Is there any research paper GooglyGuys published?

No need to imagine! They wouldn't give two metrics if they were the same.  Almost a 10 percentage point diff on mobile: https://httparchive.org/reports/chrome-ux-report#cruxFastLcp https://httparchive.org/reports/chrome-ux-report#cruxFastFcp

This is the kind of data I was looking for. It shows %s meeting a limit though, it doesn't show differences between LCP & FCP per instance. I guess since they have a query listed, it might be possible to find out that data by ourselves.

Full disclosure: I work on the Google Chrome team on Core Web Vitals and closely with the Lighthouse team.

If you hop over to https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/scorecalc/ you can see that these are

0.1 : FCP, SI, TTI
0.15 : CLS
0.25 : LCP
0.3 : TBT


That is incorrect. Those is the v8-v9 Lighthouse weightings, we're now on v12 and use the following:

0.10 : FCP, SI
0.25 : CLS
0.25 : LCP
0.30 : TBT

Now let's explain why:
We have lots of docs on the Core Web Vitals:

User-centric performance metrics explaining why the newer metrics are more important than older ones like DomContentLoaded
Web Vitals explaining the Core Web Vitals  (LCP, INP, CLS), and other web vitals (FCP, TTFB, TBT)
How the Core Web Vitals metrics thresholds were defined

We think the 3 CWVs are the best measures of measuring actual user experience and if you were to only look at 3 metrics, then those are the ones to concentrate on!
So in an ideal world, Lighthouse would reflect than and be weighted 0.333/0.333/0.333 for those. And the v12 weightings are not far off this to be honest! And certainly closer than the v8/v9 weightings you showed where CLS (fairly new at that time) was under weighted.
However, while LCP is important (and if only measuring one loading metric, then measure that!), FCP and Speed Index are also of value. Hence they get a small percentage in the weighting too. Not as much as LCP, but not nothing either.

From my observation FCP and LCP are often identical.

That may be the case for some sites, but in MANY cases it is not true.

I struggled to find a solid basis for the heuristic that places much more value on LCP

We wanted to chose one metric to represent "loading" speed and in our opinion LCP does that. When the "main content" is loaded, the user can start interacting with the page. The "main content" is often the largest piece of content — not always, but often. On the other hand, when the first paint happens (FP), or even the First Contentful Paint (FCP) the page may still not be that useful. And similarly waiting of everything to finish, would measure  many perfectly useful pages as being slower then their user-perceived speed.
Now the above weightings, while close to the Core Web Vitals, do have a slight imbalance compared to the Core Web Vitals, it's true:

Loading (LCP, FCP, SI) - 0.45
Interactivity (TBT) - 0.30
Visual Stability (CLS) - 0.25

Though it's arguable that SI could be considered Loading and partially Visual Stability so maybe should be split between them balancing it up a little but still biased towards Loading.
Anyway, Lighthouse, like many (if not all!) lab performance measuring tools, is primarily good at measuring loading performance. This is partially a reflection on history (that was what we used to concentrate on, in the past, so a lot of tooling has grown around that over the years, while the other two are newer!), and partially a reflection of what those tools ever can be good at.
Post-load CLS is a real thing where content loads late as you scroll and interact with the site, but Lighthouse doesn't measure that.
Similarly INP is not possible to measure fully in the lab and TBT is proxy for that, that can be useful, but also sometimes can't. See this Twitter thread I posted recently for more details.
So Lighthouse concentrating more on what it's good at (loading metrics), again makes sense. This explains why the score is a little biased towards Loading.
Don't over fret about the Lighthouse score
So hopefully that explains the relational of the current weighting. But I'd also like to say that people often over-index on the Lighthouse performance score.
A green 100 is a lovely thing to get but the score is just a summary indicator of possible page performance issues, because of the limitations of lab tooling. Measuring the Core Web Vitals in the field is MUCH more important as it reflects how users are actually experiencing your site.
Who cares if you have a perfect, green Lighthouse 100 score, if the field measures show the users have a much worse experience?
On the other hand if users are having great experiences, despite a Lighthouse score of 60, then you've less to worry about. There's things you can improve, but overall you're doing great already.
This is why PageSpeed Insights shows the field metrics FIRST, and the Lighthouse Lab metrics beneath are used to give further insights into how to improve those.
So it's good to be inquisitive about the decisions tooling authors make, and was happy to give my insights into those decisions, but try to remember the ultimate reason why we're looking at things like the Lighthouse Performance score and make sure you're not losing sight of that.

Thank you for the long answer. I am still interested to see if we have sample values from WebMetrics which will show the differences between FCP and LCP in practice. Obviously I wouldn't dream of disputing that they can be different, my question is around what that difference is in practice in terms of percentiles, percentiles being the methodology used to calculate weights elsewhere. I did wonder if squaring SpeedIndex would be an improvement for Loading measure : i.e. Sum(1 - (SSIM(i,n)^2)

Can you explain what you mean by sample values? You can create your own sample values to see “difference in practice” by running Lighthouse yourself, no?

Let's pick the first site that comes into my head - stackoverflow! https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-stackoverflow-com/mtrkkykl11?form_factor=mobile. In the field LCP is a full second after FCP on mobile. In the lab in Lighthouse it's 6 seconds later than FCP.

The reasons they are different is late loading content (e.g. a hero image set in a CSS file that takes a while to download, or where the LCP is a cookie banner that loads late, or Client Side Rendering SPA that needs to execute a lot of JavaScript before it can show the main content. In all cases the FCP is shown first (which might be some text, other images, or a loading spinner) but the LCP is later.

If you want to do wide scale analysis of most of the active web, then you look at the CrUX dataset in BigQuery (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/bigquery) for field data, or the HTTP Archive for lab data (https://har.fyi/), including Lighthouse runs for every site.

When I look at https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-stackoverflow-com/mtrkkykl11?form_factor=desktop they are 0.2s apart in the 75th percentile, which suggests that there isn't generally a difference the user can perceive. Obviously in that example there is a difference from the mobile hit. But the crux/bigquery looks to be what I was after. Cheers for that.


Lighthouse weighs each lab equivalent metric based on what we believe creates the best incentives to improve overall page experience for users.
LCP, CLS, and TBT are very good metrics and that's why they are the three highest-weighted metrics in the performance score.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/docs/v8-perf-faq.md#why-are-the-core-web-vitals-metrics-weighted-differently-in-the-performance-score
Ultimately, at the end of the day, it's the Google gang saying, "this is what the weights should be."
While their weights are not "coming from" the HTTP Archive, it does appear that they use the Archive's corpus of data to project how their weights will impact the web's scores.

Thanks for the answer you actually thought of yourself. It is disappointing for me not to be able to see actual figures and research that went into LCP. Speed Index already covers some of what they do, indeed I suppose one should think of LCP and FCP as hacks to correct speed index. Although given the weight of LCP, perhaps FCP and SI are hacks to correct LCP!

Hmm, I don’t think I quite agree! The metrics relate but I don’t think SI is the goal. Rather than hacks, I view them as discrete metrics
